# Laravel 5: How can I load database values into the config/services.php file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a multi-tenant app I'm working on and while adding the socialite package, I tried to load the custom facebook client_id and client_secret for the specific website from the database. I can't really use the env variables because each site will have it's own custom facebook keys.

It seems you can't really call a model's method on the config/services.php file because it might not have been loaded yet. I've tried going through the request lifecycle docs to resolve this to no avail.

I've also tried to create a service provider to get the value from my Business model's method and set it as a constant but still, by the time it's available in the app, the config/services.php file has been loaded.

Here's where I want the database value available:

**config/services.php**

```
'facebook' => [
  'client_id' => \App\Business::getAppKeys()->fb_client_id,
  'client_secret' => 'your‐fb‐app‐secret',
  'redirect' => 'http://your‐callback‐url',
],
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function connection() on null

Comment: You could flip the problem on it's head, and create a `ConfigServiceProvider`, query the database for the values you require, and then write them to a config file thereafter.

Comment: @fubar I have tried this but  the config values still aren't available to the services config file on time. Is there a way to change load order of the files in the config folder?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Config files should be readable and writeable from a service provider.

Comment: What I meant was that if I check for       dd(config('settings.fb')); in the config/services.php file, I find that it is null, but it is available in the controllers which means it is being set after it is needed

Comment: I've added an answer illustrating what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not want to do this. Initialising DB connections from a model requires all config to be loaded, and you intend to use these connections to define your config. You've found yourself having a circular dependency problem.

I'd like to suggest having a look at the socialite package you're trying to use. If no facilities exist in the service to set/override credentials at runtime, see if you're able to extend the service with your own implementation that does allow for that. I think that will be the only way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Besides all that, config files are supposed to be composed of only scalar values and arrays, so that they can be cached.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a really quick example of what I'm talking about.

Using the following, I am able to query the database, grab some details and write them to a config file, before the rest of my application is initialised.

See how I'm able to access the value in a route?

```
// app/Providers/ConfigServiceProvider.php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Country;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $countries = Country::pluck('name', 'iso_code');
        config()->set(['app.countries' => $countries->toArray()]);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}


// config/app.php

// ...

'providers' => [
    // ...
    App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],

// ...


// routes/web.php

Route::get('config', function () {
    dd(config('app.countries'));
});
```

Comment: This is all well and good but have you tried to diedump config('app.countries') in the config/services.php file which is where I need it? I've done it and it is null. It is available in my routes and controllers but not in my config/services.php file...This means that socialite will receive null as the facebook client id in my case.

Comment: Don't you use the Socialite in your controller? If so, using the above, you should be able to set the driver config values prior to them being needed. That's what I was trying to demonstrate. Why are you `dd()` in the config file?

Comment: I was using dd() to see whether variables in the config file are successfully being loaded into config/services.php before moving on to other steps. Let me finish configuring the entire package and see what the results will be because the other alternative might be to actually set the config values directly in vendor\laravel\socialite\src\SocialiteManager.php

Comment: To my knowledge, config files are loaded prior to service providers. So if you `dd()` the value in the config file, it will be `null`, because the service provider won't have been called yet. If you `dd()` the value just prior to usage, then it should have already been set.

Comment: I've tried and unfortunately it doesn't work. I've had to use the config file variables we set in the service provider directly in the socialite package itself after which I was successful. It's dirty, I know, but I don't have a choice for now. It seems also that if indeed the config file we set in the service provider was available, we should be able to dd() it in the config/services.php file as well. It just isn't available by the time it's needed. Thanks for taking the time to respond. Let me know if you find something cleaner.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to `dd()` in `config/services.php` too, because that would run before the service provider. But okay, if it doesn't work, I don't have any other suggestions I'm afraid.

Comment: If you use database in provider boot() method, then you will get Exception during `composer install` with not initialized database. So you must check if connection to database and table with settings exists.

Something like this:
    private function connectionToDatabaseExists(): bool
    {
        try {
            DB::connection()->getPdo();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function isSettingsTableExists(): bool
    {
        return Schema::hasTable('settings');
    }